# How to add pod 0.3.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have downloaded a PNChart which is present in the given link

https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart/blob/master/README.md

To Run the project i need to follow these requirements

**CocoaPods is the recommended way to add PNChart to your project.
Add a pod entry for PNChart to your Podfile pod 'PNChart', '~> 0.5'
Install the pod(s) by running pod install.
Include PNChart wherever you need it with #import "PNChart.h".**

without installing them i get these errors. and I dont know how to add these to the project can someone guide me the process and explain what all these are ? and why i have to add these ? I get the below errors when i run the downloaded project from GitHub . I have no knowledge in mac and Terminal

[image]

Comment: Did you run `pod install` from the command line in the root of your project?

Comment: i run the code in the path in Termila... pod install.. but command not found

Comment: the first point says 1.Add a pod entry for PNChart to your podfile pod 'PNChart' ~> 0.5  How to do so ?

Comment: You need to install [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org), and it is `pod install` not `pad install`.

Comment: ya i did pod install but command not found. I know zero knowledge in this. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you don't have the cocoapods installed. You need it to run the Pod Install command.

Open your terminal, run:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Then, go to your project directory in terminal, you can use the "cd" command to do it.

When you are in your project's folder, run pod install.

Comment: and when i run pod install after going to project directory it says command not found

Comment: What are you exactly typing in terminal at the project's folder?

Comment: i type  PNChart-master admin$ run pod install    i get this 
-bash: run: command not found

Comment: haha. Try just "pod install" without "run"

The term "run" is about running a command.

Comment: no friend  "run : command not found" is what i get in return. i am just writing "pod install"

Comment: If you run `gem query --local` can you see any cocoapods in the list?

Comment: yes when i run the query i get this cocoapods (0.35.0)
cocoapods-core (0.35.0) 
cocoapods-downloader (0.8.0)
cocoapods-plugins (0.3.2)
cocoapods-trunk (0.4.1)
cocoapods-try (0.4.2)

Comment: i resolved 2 errors. used setup and installed fixed... the one issue remaining is ld: library not found for -lPods-UICountingLabel

Comment: one issue remaining pls tell me how to fix it.. the issue is ld: library not found for -lPods-UICountingLabel

Comment: Check the Podfile with a text editor (easier way), does it have `pod 'PNChart', '~> 0.5'`? If not, add, save. And run `pod update`. P.s. The Podfile should be in your project's directory

Comment: u r awesome thanks for u r patiece with me. i wish i could give u Thousand votes ups. thanks friend

Comment: No problem! I had my problems with cocoapods once too. Glade I could help.

Comment: i get an linker error here what do i do ?ld: 89 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65530/discussion-between-kio-coan-and-iworld).